# How to set a variable page size in iReport

Tags: ireport, page-size

I want to print tickets in a termic printer, but it the information can use 3" or 25" of paper of length. If I set a page size of 25", i waste a lot of paper because is printed the white space.

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, it was more easy than i thought.

Theres is an option in main element report (first element in Report Inspector window) called **Pagination**. Just check **Ignore Pagination**.

Well, that's all.